# How to find lat/long coordinates in a image, If we have lat/long of 4 corners

Tags: python, math, location

I have a image. I know lat & long of all 4 corners. I want to find lat & long of a specific point.

In the below image, I know lat/long of all 4 corners (red point). I want to find the lat/long of blue point. I know the pixels coordinates of the blue point in this image. Let's say, it is 200px left and 233px bottom (from top).

[image]

Comment: You might take a look at "bilinear interpolation in a quadrilateral", e.g. https://www.particleincell.com/2012/quad-interpolation/

Comment: Very related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071685/python-implementation-of-bilinear-quadrilateral-interpolation

Comment: ....hmm, do you use a simple Lat/Long -> x/y or a different map projection?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer: Here is the Python code

```
def GetLatandLong(top_Left_Lat, top_Left_Long, bottom_Right_Lat, bottom_Right_Long,img_Width,img_Height, target_Top, target_Left):
    diff_Between_Top_Bottom_Lat = bottom_Right_Lat - top_Left_Lat
    percentage_Of_Total_Lat_In_Picture = diff_Between_Top_Bottom_Lat/90*100
    image_Size_Height_Required_To_Cover_Entire_Earth = img_Height/percentage_Of_Total_Lat_In_Picture*100
    top_Left_Percentage_Of_Lat = top_Left_Lat/90*100
    top_Left_Pixel_In_Image = image_Size_Height_Required_To_Cover_Entire_Earth*top_Left_Percentage_Of_Lat/100
    target_Pixel_In_Whole_Earth_Image = top_Left_Pixel_In_Image + target_Top
    percentage_Of_Target_In_Image = target_Pixel_In_Whole_Earth_Image/image_Size_Height_Required_To_Cover_Entire_Earth*100    
    target_Lat = percentage_Of_Target_In_Image*90/100


    diff_Between_Top_Bottom_Long = bottom_Right_Long - top_Left_Long
    percentage_Of_Total_Long_In_Picture = diff_Between_Top_Bottom_Long/180*100
    image_Size_Width_Required_To_Cover_Entire_Earth = img_Width/percentage_Of_Total_Long_In_Picture*100
    top_Left_Percentage_Of_Long = top_Left_Long/180*100
    top_Left_Pixel_In_Image = image_Size_Width_Required_To_Cover_Entire_Earth*top_Left_Percentage_Of_Long/100
    target_Pixel_In_Whole_Earth_Image = top_Left_Pixel_In_Image + target_Left
    percentage_Of_Target_In_Image = target_Pixel_In_Whole_Earth_Image/image_Size_Width_Required_To_Cover_Entire_Earth*100    
    target_Long = percentage_Of_Target_In_Image*180/100






    return target_Lat,target_Long


target_Lat,target_Long = GetLatandLong(52.871983, 8.642317, 52.869069, 8.659905,1200,218, 180, 650)

print(target_Lat,target_Long)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `intermediatePointTo` function of [geodesy](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy). [Here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) the explanation.
It's in JavaScript but you can easily convert it to Python.